# Prove the two identities

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The functions $x$ and $y$ are defined by
$x'(t)=y^2(t)$  and  $y'(t)=−x^2(t)$,
initial conditions
$x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=1$.

We have $x^3(t)+y^3(t)=1$ for all $t$.

Prove that   $\frac{x(t)}{y(t)}=-x(-t)$   and   $y(t)y(-t)=1$

Thanks

Comment: What is meant by "the function xx"? Is it same as just $x(t)$ i.e. a function $x$ of one variable $t$? Also are we assuming the cubes sum to $1$ as part of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For the first.

If
$f(t)
=x^3(t)+y^3(t)
=x^3+y^3
$,
then
$f'(t)
=3x'x^2+3y'y^2
=3(y^2x^2-x^2y^2)
=0$.
Therefore
$f$ is constant,
and since
$f(0) = 1$,
$f(t) = 1$
for all $t$.